# i have problem with out of context for session in flask

Tags: python, flask, session, babeljs, flask-babel

i wrote multiple languages panel with flask and flask-babel and set lang in session for detect languages and load content and i use factory pattern for create app.
now i want to use session out of context of my app to set locale for babel

```
def get_locale():
   if session.get("lang", False):
       session["lang"] = "fa"
   return session["lang"]

babel = Babel()


def create_app(config_name: str = 'dev') -> Flask:
    app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/assets')

    app.config.from_object(cfg[config_name])

    with app.app_context():
        babel.init_app(app, locale_selector=get_locale)

    return app
```

i tried g but its not working in every request g is empty

Answer (score 0):

Try using cookies. I dont think that flasks session-system is reachable from the Frontend. This worked for me quite well.

Comment: i try use cookie but i have same error

Comment: @dot1mav please edit ur initial question and append the code u used for the cookies. Also please explain what exactly ur Frontend is doing to get the Locale-Data from the backend

Answer (score 0):

I think you dont need to use "with app.app_context()" when initializing babel.